# Python - Transformar intervalo de linhas em colunas

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

Eu tenho um DataFrame com uma coluna e 5.000 linhas.

O que eu preciso fazer é pegar intervalos de 48 linhas e transpor para 48 colunas com todo o dataFrame

Como está:

```
 1. 0.35
 2. 0.21
 3. 0.45
 4. ...
 5. 0.12
 6. 0.34
```

Como preciso:

```
[0.35 0.21 0.45 ... 0.12 0.34]
```

Comment: E o que já tentou fazer? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um código que pode ser alterado para diversas quantidades de linhas a serem transpostas em colunas. Primeiro, criei um `DataFrame` com 40 elementos (1, 2, ..., 40) em uma coluna e armazenei as suas dimensões:

```
import pandas as pd
dados = list(range(1, 41, 1))
dados= pd.DataFrame(dados)
nlinhas,ncols=dados.shape
```

Resultado de `print(dados.head())`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, defini quantas colunas o `DataFrame` com os dados transposto deve ter. No meu exemplo, escolhi 6, no seu seriam 48. Com base no número de elementos (número de linhas) e na quantidade de colunas, crio uma lista com os índices iniciais de cada linha no novo `DataFrame`.

```
# número de colunas no DataFrame a ser criado (transposto):
ncolunas = 6

lista = list(range(0, nlinhas,ncolunas))
```

O `DataFrame.append()` junta os dados com base no nome das colunas. Portanto, para que os dados fiquem alinhados, devem ter sempre colunas com o mesmo nome. Um `DataFrame` vazio é criado para armazenar os dados transpostos e as colunas são nomeadas (C0, C1, ..., C5):

```
colnomes=["C"+str(i) for i in range(0, ncolunas)]
dados_transpostos = pd.DataFrame(columns=colnomes)
```

Por fim um `for loop` itera sobre os valores da lista de índices, transpõe as colunas de interesse, checa se há a quantidade esperada de colunas - se não houver, adiciona -, renomeia as colunas e apensa ao `DataFrame` criado para armazenar os dados transpostos.

```
for i in lista:
    df=dados[i:i+ncolunas].transpose()
    if df.shape[1] != len(colnomes):
        addcol = len(colnomes)-df.shape[1]
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=['B'+str(i) for i in range(0, addcol)])])
    df.columns = dados_transpostos.columns.values
    dados_transpostos= dados_transpostos.append(df, ignore_index = True)

print(dados_transpostos)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, Marina. No meu código, ele estava add tudo em uma unica linha, mas com seu exemplo me ajudou muito.

Comment: Se imagino corretamente o seu código, a cada iteração 48 linhas eram selecionadas e transpostas. Ao transpor, o "nome" (index/índice) da linha passava a ser 0. Se todas as vezes que vc transpuser, o índice for o mesmo, as novas colunas só conterão elementos na linha 0. No código que eu propus, o termo `ignore_index = True` faz com que cada linha seja renomeada ao ser incluída no `DataFrame`. Caso esse termo seja omitido, todas as linhas ficam com o índice 0. Como as colunas têm o mesmo nome, os dados são adicionados às colunas criadas. Caso não as nomeasse, os dados ficariam em uma única linha